# Do gold quality wild crops yield better seeds?

Tags: stardew-valley

In spring, for example, you can craft wild seeds from daffodils, horseradish, leeks and dandelion. Will using gold quality plants yield better quality seeds? For example, are these seeds more likely to produce higher quality crops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All seeds are exactly the same. Crop quality is determined by your Farming skill - or the Foraging skill in the case of wild seeds - and the fertilizer you've used, if any.

Answer (score 4):

As Wrigglenite mentioned quality is primarily determined by farming skill and fertilizer, seeds crafting from your crafting menu or using the seed maker don't have a quality level regardless of the ingredients you use.

However, if you are looking to create wild seeds you can guarantee their outcome without fertilizer.  If you pick the Botanist perk when you level up to 10 then all foraged items (Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter seeds all result in crops that can be foraged) will be iridium quality.

[Foraging info](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Foraging#Foraging_Skill)